# Issue error checking a batch file run via VBScript

Tags: windows, batch-file, vbscript

I am unsure why `InstallResult` always returns a 1 in my VBScript. I have put an echo in my batch file to confirm if I delete the source file before a copy it returns a 4 and that it returns nothing if it is successful. Any help would be appreciated. My files should do the following:

1. Copy a script from a network share to the local machine.
2. Run a batch file to install office (currently some test code for error checking). The batch file should run and post an error code on exit or a 0 if successful.
3. Go back to the VBScript to error check and run another cleanup VBScript.

Here is my code:

**Run install bat (VBScript)**

```vb
Dim objshell, InstallResult

Dim FSO
Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

FSO.CopyFile "\\altirisdata\AssetMgmt\Tools\WSM\DeleteOffice13Package.vbs", "C:\source\DeleteOffice13Package.vbs"
'DeleteMS2013FilePath = objShell.run ("c:\source\DeleteOffice13Package.vbs", 0, True)

WScript.Sleep 3000

Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
InstallResult = objShell.run ("cscript.exe C:\source\Microsoft_Office_2013_01\install.bat", 0, True)

WScript.Echo InstallResult

If InstallResult <> 0 Then WScript.Echo "Unable to install Microsoft Office 2013. Please manually check the install results"

If InstallResult = 0 Then 
    DeleteDelScript = objShell.Run("cscript.exe c:\source\DeleteOffice13Package.vbs", 0, True)
End If

If DeleteDelScript = 0 Then 
    FSO.DeleteFile("C:\source\DeleteOffice13Package.vbs")
End If

Set FSO = nothing

WScript.Quit
```

**install.bat**

```batch
@echo off

xcopy "C:\source\test again\test.txt" "C:\Temp\Temp1\TempTest" /y

if %errorlevel% neq 0 (
    exit /b %errorlevel%
)

exit
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get a return value of 1, because you're trying to run a *batch* script with a *VBScript* interpreter:

```vb
InstallResult = objShell.run ("cscript.exe C:\sourc...l.bat", 0, True)
```

Remove `cscript.exe` from the commandline, or replace it with `%COMSPEC% /c`:

```vb
InstallResult = objShell.run ("%COMSPEC% /c C:\sourc...l.bat", 0, True)
```

---

As a side note, you shouldn't need a condition in your batch script. Simply returning the errorlevel should suffice:

```batch
@echo off
xcopy "C:\source\test again\test.txt" "C:\Temp\Temp1\TempTest" /y
exit /b %errorlevel%
```